# Evernote Python get simplified article

Tags: python, evernote

Got one little problem with Evernote python sdk.

What i do really need is to collect a collection of document from web. And i do need only article-content text.

I tried to use Evernote Python SDK (cause Python is similar to R, i usually use).

But what i do really need - is the same functionality as Evernote WebClipper.

I need to get a "simplified article" (only content part of the webpage, not menu-links, footer and comments).

1. take url of a webpage to get content from
2. call evernote func and get the "simplified article" of the page
3. return simplified_article.content #doesn't matter plain text or html

so, how can i do it? It would be nice to see the code (Step_2 only required).
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

According to [API for Web Clipper? - Evernote for Developers - Evernote User Forum](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/37175-api-for-web-clipper/) (04.2013),

> Unfortunately our clipper technology isn't available in our SDK.